# XML - what's a tag use to run a local application in xml

Tags: xml, local, google-earth

In google earth , i have a place mark, and this place mark is written by xml. I want to run a local application when i click this place mark. Therefore I added   code** in the code of this place mark, but when i click this place mark my local appication isn't run.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Placemark</name>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>13.48017999508694</longitude>
        <latitude>49.24758982142959</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>-0.1609784865516569</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>177060.1424456803</range>
        <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
    </LookAt>
    <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
  **<local >"F:\need\Project\Tablo\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe"</local>**
        <coordinates>13.48017999508694,49.24758982142959,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Note you can (and should in this case) [edit] your question. Try to include more details, possible error-messages and try to avoid things like ??? as this is considered rude :) You should as well read the [tour] and look on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: Thank you,I edited

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that this is a feature that Google Earth supports?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I think it's possible